# Move-Item -exclude throwing redundant error

Tags: powershell

I'm moving a group of files from a directory and I'm using the `-exclude` modifier to exclude files with a .gpg extension:

```
Move-Item -path $encrypted_folder\*.* -EXCLUDE *.gpg -destination $final_dir
```

And while this works fine by moving every non-.gpg file, I get the following error every time `Move-Item` encounters a .gpg file:

```
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'C:\Users\ThisUser\Documents\PGP Encryption test\UUID\xxxx.gpg' does not exist.
At C:\Users\ThisUser\Documents\PGP Encryption test\yyyy.ps1:41 char:1
+ Move-Item -path $encrypted_folder\*.* -EXCLUDE *.gpg -destination $final_dir
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Why is it complaining that it can't move a .gpg item because it doesn't exist, when I've set the command to exclude .gpg items? (which definitely exist). The exclusion is occurring, and a subsequent command to `-include` .gpg files works fine, but I'm not happy with the errors on my `-exclude` command.

Comment: What happens is you put single quotes around your -Exclude items (-Exclude '*.gpg')...or create a variable called $exclude='*.gpg' then set your exclude parameter to:  -Exclude $exclude

Comment: @RMarkwald The error occurs whether I use an $exclude variable, single quotes or no quotes. I'm just finding it bizarre that it's doing what I want it to do, yet throwing those errors as a by-product.

Comment: which ps version? It looks like this is(was) a known bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2385

Comment: What about:  Get-ChildItem -Path $encrypted_folder -Exclude $exclude -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination $final_dir...of course I set $exclude='*.gpg'...you may or may not need -Recurse, I guess depends on if there's other folders etc you want it to also go through.

Comment: @wmz Good find -  My PSVersion is 3.0; BuildVersion is 6.2.9200.22198. The bug must have been around for a while as the version in the github post you mention is 6.0.0-alpha. I'll see if I can update, which is always a struggle on these corporate networks..

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite the expression as follows:

```
gci $encrypted_folder\*.* -exclude *.gpg | move-item -destination $final_dir
```

You may also build more sophisticated filters using `where-object` and `-match/notmatch`, *for example exclude only those with 4 or more chars before extension*:

```
gci |? name -notmatch '^.{4,}\.gpg$' | [rest of processing here]
```

**Explanation**

As noted in comments, this error is reported here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2385.  I can replicate it in PS 4 as well:

```
$psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.18728
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

New-Item -Name "foo.txt" -ItemType File
New-Item -Name "bar.txt" -ItemType File
Move-Item -Path ".\*" -Destination "move.txt" -Exclude "bar*"

Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'C:\temp\test\bar.txt' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-Item -Path ".\*" -Destination "move.txt" -Exclude "bar*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

The fix for this is in the not-yet-released version 6 (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/v6.0.0-beta.5).